# Sorting in Heatmap in Orange

Tags: orange

I am new in this community and hope to find some hints. At the moment I am a little bit confused by orange. In the documentation it is shown, that you can sort within the heat map rows or columns, but this option is not there...I only can merge by clusters.

Maybe a little bit more background. I measured different objects in one (microscopy) image and measured the mean intensity over all channels. Now I would like to find interesting cells by clustering or heat map visualisation. Due to the fact, that I have thousands of objects some sorting would maybe help to extract the information...tracing back to the image finding the cells.

All the best

Ralf